# Conversion OF FIFO code from Java to c#

Tags: c#, java, fifo

### couple of days ago i posted a topic about fifo programming and how to do it because the topic was a bit broad and vague and lacks coding example, so i followed experts advice and searched for codes and tried a bit of coding. and i knew exactly what i wanted to do

i want to create a DES (Discrete event simulation) for the FIFO (first in first out) scheduling algorithm using the C# as my programming language.

so i searched the net and i couldn't find something really helpful in c# for guidance but i found exactly what i wanted to in java codes. which i will post now

The process of Initialization

```
    Queue q = new Queue();
    EventQueue eventq = new EventQueue();
    Random rand = new Random();
    Distribution interarrivalTimeDist =
    new ExponentialDistribution(lambda, rand);
    Distribution serviceTimeDist =
    new ExponentialDistribution(mu, rand);
    double t = 0;
    // generate first arrival
    eventq.addEvent(new Event(Event.ARRIVAL,
    interarrivalTimeDist.nextRandom()));
```

Main program

```
while (t < simLength) {
Event e = eventq.nextEvent();
t = e.getTime();
switch (e.getType()) {
case Event.ARRIVAL : {
// handle arrival
}
case Event.DEPARTURE : {
// handle departure
}
}
}
```

Case of Arrival

```
case Event.ARRIVAL : {
// schedule next arrival
eventq.addEvent(new Event(Event.ARRIVAL,
t + interarrivalTimeDist.nextRandom()));
double serviceTime =
serviceTimeDist.nextRandom();
q.addCustomer(new Customer(t, serviceTime));
if (q.getSize() == 1) {
eventq.addEvent(new Event(Event.DEPARTURE,
t + serviceTime));
}
break;
}
```

Case of departure

```
case Event.DEPARTURE : {
q.removeCustomer(t);
if (q.getSize() > 0) {
double serviceTime =
q.getCustomerAt(0).getServiceTime();
eventq.addEvent(new Event(Event.DEPARTURE,
t + serviceTime));
}
break;
}
```

any clues or guidance how to convert this code to c#?? 
and help will help highly appreciated it 
PS:- for the experts please show some tolerance if my topic wasn't as professional as you guys thought it will be 
thanks

Comment: Try copying and pasting this into Visual Studio, a few compiler error fixes and change in the name of collections should get you up and running.

Comment: You mean the c# compiler right?? compile there and see what shall happen ?

Comment: what tool are you using to program in c#? Visual Studio Express? Make a c# project in Visual Studio (vs), paste this code somewhere, and see what happens :)

Comment: yes, i'm using the visual studio, well i did that and i have lots of errors, don't forget there's number of libraries that the author used in the java i don't know their equivalent in c#,. i'm not being strict to this code, if you have anything that resembles fifo discrete event simulation in c# plz share it

Comment: There is a Queue in System.Collections, and a generic Queue in System.Collections.Generic (best to use the latter). For the other errors, research+test each one, and if you have trouble, make a unique SO question for each one, not the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds a lot like "how do I program this idea", and isn't a good SO question. You should design a lot about what you want to do, build it in steps, and come here with specific questions you have, not broad ideas or lots of code.

To answer just FIFO, that is a `queue`. Read about [queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) and practice with them.

Comment: i know the whole idea of the queue and how to do it in C#, queue aren't my problem at all, building a Discrete event simulation is a bit big for me or at least for now that's the problem, i have scheme for the java and i'm working on it, but you know the tunnel vision that might strike you out of the nowhere that's what happening to me.